# How do I reference an unsigned assembly from a VSTO Word Doc project?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, word-2007

I created a new project in VS2008. Project type

```
Visual C# > Office > 2007 > Word 2007 Document
```

Added some code.. got Word to do a few jumps through some custom hoops.. all fine. Now I need to reference another assembly (`CopyLocal as false`) which is **not signed**. So I add the project reference. Now the project will not build complaining

> error MSB3188: Assembly 'X.dll' must
>   be strong signed in order to be marked
>   as a prerequisite.

The [error code page is concise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228132(vs.80).aspx) (now accustomed to this)
Been googling and reading posts ever since.. No Luck.

How do I get around this ? Or is the hidden commandment that all references (for VSTO?) must be strong named / signed.
I cannot sign `X.dll` and be done with it because it is a binary that I don't control also it depends on another bunch of unsigned dlls.. can't set off a chain sign reaction.

**Update**: Solved the build issue by turning **CopyLocal=True**. But this meant dumping  the referenced X.DLL and all its dependencies into the bin\debug folder... Ughh! Tried creating a subfolder called `bin\debug\refExecs` and referencing X.dll `CopyLocal=false` from there. The error message was back.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get around this should be to load the assembly dynamically during runtime.

Googling for a solution brought up the following [posting](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VisualStudio/microsoft.public.vstudio.general/2006-05/msg00056.html), maybe this is of any help?